# Get rid of brackets when displaying results from sql query in a list box (Tkinter and Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am building an application where, simply, people enter data into a database and they can retrieve their data by searching for it. I am using sqlite 3 and Tkinter in python to build this program. When I'm searching for data and it displays in the Tkinter list box it shows as: 
{Bob Jones} name@email.com {John Jones}

How do I display the query without those curly brackets?

Backend code:

```
def search(parent_email=""):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("parentsevening.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE parent_email=? ORDER BY app_time", (parent_email,))
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

Front end code:

```
def search_command():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    for row in parents_backend.search(parent_email.get()):
        list1.insert(END,row)
```

Comment: You use a `SELECT *` and give no description for the table.How can we guess what the query could return? BTW, can it return more than one line?

Comment: The column headers are: id | parent_name | parent_email | student_name

Comment: Are the curly braces inside the database field?

Comment: No, they only show in the list box

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting a python list into a listbox, but the insert method expects a string. You are responsible for converting the data to a string before inserting the data. If you don't explicitly do the conversion, tkinter will do the conversion for you. That may yield brackets in the data due to the fact that the underlying tcl interpreter will use its own syntax to preserve the list structure of the original data.

For example, if you want the elements in the list to appear with spaces between them you can use `join`:

```
list1.insert(END, " ".join(row))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed to code to `list1.insert(END,str(row))`, which gets rid of the curly brackets, but now it shows: `(1, u'Name', u'name@email.com', u'NameOne')`. So gets rid of the curly brackets but now it has brackets on the whole query and the 'u's.

Comment: @ElisJD: yes, that's what `str` does with a list. Bottom line: it's up to you to conver the list into whatever format you want to see in the UI.

Comment: Do you have how I can convert the list just to show the values of: **id  parent_name  parent_email. student_name**  in that format?

Comment: @ElisJD: my answer shows you how to show the values. There are many other ways in addition to `join`. You could use string formatting, for example. It all depends on exactly what you want to see.