# Curly Brackets issue in a PySimpleGui LIST box and Python 3

Tags: python, list, sqlite, pysimplegui

I hope someone can help me this issue I am having with Python3 and PySimpleGui. I have PySimpleGui list in my app that is populated with rows from a sqlite table. I understand that ListBox accepts a python List as argument. It works well, except the fact that when a value of a table column has space between words, the Listbox enclose that value with curly brackets. If the same value is just one word, then there is no brackets. I really don't know what I am doing wrong. The code below explains better, I think. Thanks for any input on this.

```
def populate_dir(group) :
    # Populate a List with query results

    global people_list
    global people_list_idx
    people_list = []
    thisfilter = group

    if thisfilter == 'All' :
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts_Main WHERE ?'
        thisfilter = '1'
    else :
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts_Main WHERE Status = ?'

    lcursor = con_.cursor()
    lcursor.execute(sql, (thisfilter,))
    result = lcursor.fetchall()
    # people_list is a pysimplegui List
    # Column [0] in eachrec is a integer primary autoincrement ID
    # Column [2] is a sqlite Text field which holds a person full name with spaces betwwen names.

    for eachrec in result :

        people_list.append([eachrec[0], eachrec[2]])

    # The list is then populated like this. Note that names with spaces have  undesirable curly brackets.
    # "312 John"
    # "345 {Robert MacDonald}"
    # "387 Aline"
    # "422 {Paul Redwood}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Get rid of brackets when displaying results from sql query in a list box (Tkinter and Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014309/get-rid-of-brackets-when-displaying-results-from-sql-query-in-a-list-box-tkinte),

> Bryan Oakley:
>
> You're inserting a python list into a listbox, but the insert method expects a string. You are responsible for converting the data to a string before inserting the data. If you don't explicitly do the conversion, tkinter will do the conversion for you. That may yield brackets in the data due to the fact that the underlying tcl interpreter will use its own syntax to preserve the list structure of the original data.

Maybe you can convert them into string first.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

data = [
    [312, "John"],
    [345, "Robert MacDonald"],
    [387, "Aline"],
    [422, "Paul Redwood"],
]

items = list(map(str, data))

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(items, size=(25, 4), enable_events=True, key='LISTBOX')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jason. Your code got rid of the brackets. It is functional as it should be, but is there a way to remove from the listbox all the quotes and '[ ]' ? I mean, a clean display of ID and Full Name. I apologise if it sounds trivial for you. I love this Python and PySimpleGui and I am a really a beginner in all that stuff. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Lot of ways for it, try `items = list(map(lambda x:f'{x[0]} {x[1]}', data))`