# Multiline window and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I want my multiline element to look something like this:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

But it looks like this:

```
{{Text 1}} {{Text 2}} {{Text 3}}
```

My code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout_list = [
    ['Text 1'],
    ['Text 2'],
    ['Text 3']
]

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline(layout_list, s=(60, 5), disabled=True, key='key-multiline')]
]

window = sg.Window('Help!', layout=layout, margins=(1, 1))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [Curly Brackets issue in a PySimpleGui LIST box and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011938/curly-brackets-issue-in-a-pysimplegui-list-box-and-python-3/69012553#69012553)

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout_list = [
    ['Text 1'],
    ['Text 2'],
    ['Text 3'],
]

text = '\n'.join(item[0] for item in layout_list)    # Convert layout_list into string

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline(text, s=(60, 5), disabled=True, key='key-multiline')]
]

sg.Window('Help!', layout=layout, margins=(1, 1)).read(close=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! i wanted to keep the list in the same format so this really helps.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it using `Listbox` instead of `Multiline`. The code is as shown below. Please note the difference that while using Listbox, the `layout_list` is not a list of list, rather simply a list.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg                        # Part 1 - The import


layout_list = [
    'Text 1',
    'Text 2',
    'Text 3'
]

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox( values= layout_list, s=(60, 5), disabled=True, key='key-multiline')]
]

window = sg.Window('Help!', layout=layout, margins=(1, 1))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window.read()
```

The output window is as required.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i picked Jason Yang answer because I wanted to keep the list in the same form.

Comment: yes! definitely! +1 to Jason's answer, it preserves the input format!